# Simple unique_ptr issue

Tags: c++, c++11

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string> foo_ptr(new std::string("foo"));
foo_ptr.reset(foo_ptr.get());
std::cout << *foo_ptr << std::endl; //prints "foo" so obj hasn't been deleted
//runtime error: "pointer being freed was not allocated"
```

Why do I get the runtime error, and is it just a coincidence that "foo" gets printed out?

Comment: It is undefined behavior. Anything can happen. The program ceased to be a valid program at line no: 3.

Comment: Yes it is coincidence.  Actually it's a nasal demon.

Comment: By the way: The better way to know if something was destructed is to create a class that prints something on it's destructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quotes from n3376 20.7.1.2.5/4 and 5.

> Effects: assigns p to the stored pointer, and then if the old value of the stored pointer, old_p, was not
>  equal to nullptr, calls get_deleter()(old_p).
>
> [ Note: The order of these operations is significant
>  because the call to get_deleter() may destroy *this. — end note ]

So, dereference of this pointer leads to undefined behaviour.

> Postconditions: get() == p.
> [ Note: The postcondition does not hold if the call to get_deleter()
> destroys *this since this->get() is no longer a valid expression. — end note ]

Answer (score 3):

```
foo_ptr.reset(foo_ptr.get());
```

This line will "free" the current pointer in foo_ptr, and set it to the value of foo_ptr.get(). Since the foo_ptr.get() is fetched BEFORE the value is updated, it points to the old place.

Don't do this. It leads to undefined behaviour. You should never call `reset` with the same value as it already has.

Comment: Are you sure it "first frees and then sets"? (ForEveR's answer indicates it "first sets and then frees").

Comment: @7cows: ForEveR is right on the order (the standard says so) but it doesn't change the end result. The only case where the order matters is if the old object's destructor throws (which is extremely bad practice anyway).

Comment: Conceptually, it frees the pointer it currently has, and sets the value to the one passed in. Exactly in which order that happens is not really the point of my answer.